# Node schedule run every minute within specific range of hours

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduler

I might be overlooking over already-asked-question, but I have not found it yet. Basically, did I do it right in order to execute job for every minute within 9 AM to 6 PM?

```
schedule.scheduleJob("*/1 9-18 * * *", function Job())
```

Comment: Here you can find out: https://crontab.guru/ and yes you are correct.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you very much @NicolaeMaties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron expression should be `0 * 9-18 ? * * *`

It reads 0 seconds, every minute, from 9 to 18 every day, every month, every year.

Use cron expression builder for convenience - something like this:

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: Wow I got it, thank you so much, @Charlie